# How do I predict the value based on the curve?

Tags: python, curve-fitting

I have two matrices (100,6). one of them contains PSNR values for different bitrates and the other one contains corresponding bitrates. if I plot the diagram of one row, we will have the following diagram based on the following data.

```
660256  1522800 2481600 3533650 4432290 5469300
38.3587 41.0925 42.3772 43.4243 44.1588 45.0317
```

[image]
based on the following data for bitrate `660256` we have a PSNR value of `38.3587`. my question is if I have bitrate 1000000, what will be the corresponding PSNR? I have to do this for all other columns too.do I need to use curve fitting?

```
1000000     2000000    3000000    4000000    5000000    6000000
   ?            ?         ?          ?          ?           ?
```

Answer (score 2):

If linear interpolation is good enough, you can use [`interp1d`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.interpolate.interp1d.html)

```python
import scipy 

linear_PSNR_model = scipy.interpolate.interp1d(x_values, PSNR_values)
```

Then, you can use `linear_PSNR_model` as a function like this
`linear_PSNR_model(1000000)`

Comment: my x_values is ( 1136,6) and my PSNR_values size is also (1136,6) but it produces this error:ValueError: x and y arrays must be equal in length along interpolation axis.

Comment: @david `interp1d` accepts a **1D** array for the x values

Comment: but each input has 6 columns. do you mean I have to enter each row of data separately?

Comment: @GoldenLion, could you please explain more? I am not very familiar with linear regression.

Comment: @david PSNR is a univariate function, i.e. it depends on only one variable, which means that it can be depicted in a 2D graph as in your image. As such, all its input values (or known measurements) can be represented by a 1D array. In your example, the top row contains the x-values and the bottom row the y-values. Therefore, the approach i show can be used to interpolate the data. Now, if the arrays you have are 2D for the x-values, then you need to examine exactly *what* these values are. Is each row of the (1136,6) array referring to an individual PSNR function (i.e. you have 1136 signals)?

Comment: here is an explanation of what psnr data is https://www.ni.com/en-us/innovations/white-papers/11/peak-signal-to-noise-ratio-as-an-image-quality-metric.html#:~:text=The%20term%20peak%20signal%2Dto,the%20quality%20of%20its%20representation.

Comment: as I understand psnr the mean squared error is the difference in the image quality from the target and source image.  psnr is the quality value of the image.

Comment: def psnr(original, contrast):
    mse = np.mean((original - contrast) ** 2)
    if mse == 0:
        return 100
    PIXEL_MAX = 255.0
    PSNR = 20 * math.log10(PIXEL_MAX / math.sqrt(mse))
    return PSNR

Comment: @AlexP, this code produced a linear model, right? If I want to have a more complex model like a polynomial model, what should I do? because for column sixth some rows have values less than 6MB and when I try to use your model it produces an error that "raise ValueError("A value in x_new is above the interpolation "

Comment: @david If you go through the documentation of `interp1d`, you will see that you can set its `fill_value` to `"extrapolate"`, in which case the method extrapolates the y-values for x-values outside the given range. On the same documentation page, there are "see also" suggestions, in which you can find the [`UnivariateSpline`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.interpolate.UnivariateSpline.html#scipy.interpolate.UnivariateSpline). This method will fit a 1D spline of degree `k` to your data (and there is again an extrapolation option)